# Insert txt into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, import

I would like to add a txt file inside SQL Server 2014 for analysis purposes.
Below is a line of the txt file, that comes from MixPanel.

```
{"event":"Search","properties":{"time":1445126437,"distinct_id":"S182248485740","$browser":"Chrome","$browser_version":46,"$city":"Hartlepool","$current_url":"https://flat-club.com/","$initial_referrer":"https://www.google.co.uk/","$initial_referring_domain":"www.google.co.uk","$lib_version":"2.7.1","$os":"Windows","$referrer":"https://www.google.co.uk/","$referring_domain":"www.google.co.uk","$region":"Hartlepool","$screen_height":768,"$screen_width":1366,"$search_engine":"google","ABtesting":"B","Check in date":"(21-10-2015)","Check out date":"(24-10-2015)","LoggedIn":false,"Search Location":"London, United Kingdom","Source":"homepage","Type of Stay":"Holiday","mp_country_code":"GB","mp_lib":"web"}}
```

What options do I have to make in SQL Server Import wizard, in order to insert them? I could manual replace{ etc but I have a txt 2GB that cannot be opened.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the above software.The lines are in Json format.I would try insert them into SQL server.

http://zappysys.com/onlinehelp/ssis-powerpack/index.htm#page=json-source.htm